# How can we determine the inbuilt barrierpotential and electric feld for a given band diagram?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Suppose I have got two p type silicon materials of  different concentrations (the difference in thier concentrations is small but considerable enough that their fermi levels differ by noticeable amounts).Now if I wish to make a junction device using these two p type semiconductors , I would like to know how the built in potential when plotted against length of the junction device looks like ?
Also I would like to know is there any general way of  finding built in potential from any given band diagram even if it is in terms of energy levels?